# How to switch scenes in Unity 5 without losing network connection?

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

How to switch from a "Login" scene to a "Stage1" scene in Unity 5? I establish a HLAPI connection (UNET) to the Server on a Client that connects, then the client loggs in, and then it's supposed to be sent over to another scene.

How do I do this without losing connection? Because the scene it loads is going to be entirely new without presets.

I know there is **DontDestroyOnLoa**d() but I don't think that's a good way to keep a network connection?

I do realize a few previous questions like this were asked, but I couldn't find anything pertaining to UNET and Unity 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with DontDestroyOnLoad()? That's the "official" method for keeping objects from being destroyed between scenes.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could start with a main manager scene and then load any other scene additively to it. You would keep the reference to the connection in the main manager scene.